# Can't get Hello World to work on Heroku

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku

I have my basic program

```
    def test():
        print("Hello World")
    test()
```

along with a Procfile.

```
    web: python test.py
```

When I use a one-off dyno in the command line, I get exactly what I expect. However, when I open the app in my Heroku dashboard, I get an H10 error every time. What gives?

Edit: logs

```
    2016-08-18T17:34:25.925592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hwt1.herokuapp.com request_id=a0cabc52-0f80-4094-a420-06147b8c860c fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2016-08-18T17:34:26.646976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hwt1.herokuapp.com request_id=27121a16-ad6b-489f-8ffc-1d3b5e21d225 fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed In other words, go look at the logs to find out WHY it crashed.

Comment: Run the `heroku logs` command to view what is erroring out. Paste your errors here =)

Comment: I clicked the Open App button and got this `2016-08-18T17:34:25.925592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hwt1.herokuapp.com request_id=a0cabc52-0f80-4094-a420-06147b8c860c fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-18T17:34:26.646976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hwt1.herokuapp.com request_id=27121a16-ad6b-489f-8ffc-1d3b5e21d225 fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is a web hosting service; your code needs to start a web server that binds to port 80. Just running a script that terminates immediately won't do that.